# How to set CSS3 ::selection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, selection

Does anyone have an idea how to execute this CSS rule dynamically using Javascript and then disable it (particularly to suppress annoying selection in Chrome during certain mouse gestures):

```
::selection{
    background:transparent;
}
```

E.g.: `document.body.style['::selection']['background']="transparent";`, but of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this workaround, it works:

```
var styleElem=document.createElement('style'); 
styleElem.innerHTML='::selection{ background:transparent; }';

// enable in some cases
document.head.appendChild(styleElem);

// disable when not needed
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
document.head.removeChild(styleElem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ways I can think of:

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener("selectstart", function(){return false;});
```

**CSS**

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: Tried `selectstart event`, annoying selection is still appearing in Chrome 39. With `document.body.style.pointerEvents='none';` my page doesn't react on any mouse events at all. Thank you anyway. It seems that `::selection` works nice, but I need to find a way to disable it to allow selection in some cases.